# Adding an External Link Type "Branch" to PBI and make it visible on Kanban board of TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, visualization, kanban

I would like to show explicitly linked branches form Git repository on Kanban board for PBIs and Bugs. I did try to create additional field with "LinksControl" type and then added this field to the board view.
The issue is that when I open PBI card the link to branch displays correctly but on board view the field seems to remain empty.

Any suggestion of showing links on items on the board are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields with "LinksControl" doesn't support to shows the values on the workitem cards on Kanban board.

Fields whose `Field type` is a simple type like **String**, **Int**, **Date Time**, etc and it's control is **FieldControl** could be shown on the board.

So if you want the custom field to show on the board, you need to use FieldControl. Then in the board Settings, add the Custom Field on the Card.